# How can i compare 2 tables to see the discrepancies of the data in acess

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have 2 inventory tables with same fields. Barcode is the unique identifier.  I want to compare and show the the difference in stocks and price from table 1 to 2. how do i approach this in access? I've tried using the criteria is null but to no avail.. Sorry i'm still new in database..

to be more specific. I have barcode A1 in table 1 and 2, price of A1 in table 1 is 20 and price on table 2 is 50.  I want to display this kind of data.. because it seems like our inventory isn't matching.

Comment: It looks like you are focusing on access, so your tag should be SQL, not mysql

Comment: I see, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do a two way check like this:

**First check**

```
select 
    a.barcode as referencebarcode,
    a.price as referenceprice,
    b.price,
    a.price-b.price as difference
from table1 a
left join table2 b on a.barcode = b.barcode
order by b.price
```

This will give you price difference and also show you barcodes that are present in table1 but not in table2

**Second check**

```
select 
    a.barcode as referencebarcode,
    a.price as referenceprice,
    b.price,
    a.price-b.price as difference
from table2 a
left join table1 b on a.barcode = b.barcode
order by b.price
```

This does the opposite - it shows you price difference and show you barcodes that are present in table2 but not in table1.

**Show records that have a difference using First check as an example**

```
select 
    a.barcode as referencebarcode,
    a.price as referenceprice,
    b.price,
    a.price-b.price as difference
from table1 a
left join table2 b on a.barcode = b.barcode
where (a.price-b.price) <> 0 OR a.price is null OR b.price is null
order by b.price
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But how do i filter the barcode that doesn't have any difference?

Comment: I've added an example that shows only those records that have a difference

Comment: Nvm, i just unchecked the 0 xD

Comment: SELECT 
a.barcode AS BarcodeSUS, 
a.sell AS PriceSUS, 
b.price AS PricePOS, 
a.sell-b.price AS difference
FROM SUS AS a LEFT JOIN POS AS b ON a.barcode = b.barcode
ORDER BY b.price         How do I sum the difference and show it as a different field?

Comment: I would recommend you create a new question. Include your table design, sample data and expected output. I am sure someone will be able to help out.

Answer (score 0):

A simple query should do the trick.  You could use the Access Query builder or enter straight up SQL:

```
SELECT table1.barcode, table1.price table2.price FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.barcode=table2.barcode
```